# AppleScript "Open With..." icon

Tags: applescript, uti, icon

I've written an AppleScript app that I use to open certain files with (it sends them to Vim in the Terminal).

I'd like to set all my .Tex files to automatically open with this app. The problem is this changes the files icons to the blank file icon.

Is there a way to change the app's icon? In other apps I use (non-AppleScript apps) I know how to "change" this icon by replacing it in `foo.app/contents/resources` but in my app there is no icon there yet.

Is it possible to add one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/178316/how-to-set-an-icon-for-a-file-type-on-mac/225534#225534) and [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/246476/create-new-extension-association-and-icon-in-snowleopard/246493#246493) of mine on SuperUser, where I explain how to create new or edit existing file types, including icons.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an icon file named `droplet.icns` inside the app package inside `foo.app/Contents/Resources/`.

Comment: yes this changes the droplet icon (which can be done using "get info") but doesn't change the icons of the files that are to be opened with this app. (I set the "open with" default for these file to my app)

Comment: Oh, okay, I didn't read your original question closely enough. Sorry about that. I'm guessing you'll need to create a document-based AppleScript Studio app at a minimum or more likely an AppleScriptObjC document-based app so that you get a custom file type. That might be more work than you want to put into this.

Comment: Ok how would I go about this?

Comment: I've not jumped into AppleScriptObjC yet. It's on my To Do list... So, I'm afraid I can't give you any concrete assistance.